# vb.net create a reference to an object

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to create a reference to object, where Prog2 is a reference to Prog1  Here what I need:

```
dim Prog1 as myclassprogressbar
dim Prog2 as myclassprogressbar

Prog1.initialize()
Prog1.max=10
Prog1.min=1
Prog1.value=5

Prog2.initialize()
Prog2.max=10000
Prog2.min=100
Prog2.value=500


Prog2=Prog1

Prog1.value=7


debug.print Prog2.value

7
```

Is possible create a reference to an object like this code ?

Comment: Are you sure you're _actually_ talking about VB.NET and not VBA or VB6? If so, @selfstudy did a great job explaining how it should be done. Yet, be aware that `debug.print Prog2.value` will not compile _as is_; you need to put the value in parenthesis, that is, `Debug.Print(Prog2.value)`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate the class using `New`. Then assuming `myclassprogressbar` is a class, since classes are reference type, after you assign `Prog2 = Prog1`, the variable `Prog2` will point to the same object which `Prog1` is pointing to.

So if you assign something to `Prog1.Value`, then since `Prog2` is pointing to the same object, then `Prog2.Value` will be the same value as `Prog1.Value`.

After you define Prog1 and Prog2, each of the variables are pointing to different objects in memory:

```
Variable         | Memory
---------------------------------------------------
Prog1        --> | [Min:1     Max:10     Value:5  ]
Prog2        --> | [Min:100   Max:1000   Value:500]
```

After you set `Prog2 = Prog1`, then both of them are pointing to the same object in memory and the only thing that happens to the object that you had assigned to `Prog2` is, the object is still in memory, you just lost the reference to that object:

```
Variable         | Memory
---------------------------------------------------
Prog1, Prog2 --> | [Min:1     Max:10     Value:5  ]
                 | [Min:100   Max:1000   Value:500]
```

So, if you set `Prog1.Value = 7` or `Prog2.Value = 7`, the result is the same:

```
Variable         | Memory
---------------------------------------------------
Prog1, Prog2 --> | [Min:1     Max:10     Value:7  ]
                 | [Min:100   Max:1000   Value:500]
```

You can learn more about [Value Types and Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types).